# Selecting images inside the table and inside the div

Tags: html, css

How do I select the images below (@div class="this") without selecting the images above so that I can style it with CSS?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="../index.html"><img src="../home.png"></a></td> <!-- GO BACK TO HOMEPAGE -->
        <td><a href="########"><img src="../artist.png"></a></td> <!-- GO TO ARTIST -->
        <td><img src="../portfolio.png"></td>
        <td><img src="../contact.png"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="8"><img src="../logo.png"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="8"><img src="../greenmoralesgraphic.png"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><div class="this">
        <td><img src="nostalgia.jpg" width="400px" height="400px"></td>
        <td><img src="pwersa.jpg" width="400px" height="400px"></td>
        <td><img src="tag_along.jpg" width="400px" height="400px"></td>
        <td><img src="tweet.jpg" width="400px" height="400px"></td>
        </div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: having a <div> within a <tr> is not valid. you could instead assign class="this" to the <tr> element.

Comment: @jcruz
Woah... Thank you very much. Now I can finally remove those widths and heights because I will be working with a lot of images like that. Thank you very much sir :)

Comment: You are most welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
.this img{
  border:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

This will select the images inside the class `.this`.The styles applied like  this  will apply only to the images inside the `.this` class . The space is known as  descendant combinator.[Read about descendant combinator here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors)

```css
.this img{
  border:1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="../index.html"><img src="../home.png"></a></td> <!-- GO BACK TO HOMEPAGE -->
        <td><a href="########"><img src="../artist.png"></a></td> <!-- GO TO ARTIST -->
        <td><img src="../portfolio.png"></td>
        <td><img src="../contact.png"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="8"><img src="../logo.png"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="8"><img src="../greenmoralesgraphic.png"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="this"><img src="nostalgia.jpg" width="400px" height="400px">
          <img src="pwersa.jpg" width="400px" height="400px">
          <img src="tag_along.jpg" width="400px" height="400px">
          <img src="tweet.jpg" width="400px" height="400px">
         </div>
       </td>
       <td> </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        
    </tr>
</table>
```

And Change `div` tag inside the `tr`

```css
  .this img{
      border:1px solid #f00;
    }
```

```html
 
 

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="../index.html"><img src="../home.png"></a></td> <!-- GO BACK TO HOMEPAGE -->
            <td><a href="########"><img src="../artist.png"></a></td> <!-- GO TO ARTIST -->
            <td><img src="../portfolio.png"></td>
            <td><img src="../contact.png"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="8"><img src="../logo.png"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="8"><img src="../greenmoralesgraphic.png"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="this">
                <img src="nostalgia.jpg" width="400px" height="400px"> 
             </div>
           </td>
           <td> 
             <div class="this">
                <img src="pwersa.jpg" width="400px" height="400px">
             </div>    
             
           </td>
            <td>
             <div class="this">
               <img src="tag_along.jpg" width="400px" height="400px">
             </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="this">
                   <img src="tweet.jpg" width="400px" height="400px">
              </div>
            </td>
            
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't call the images inside the div.

Comment: @CarloVillamor  td should be the direct child of tr.Cange that.Check my snippet.only borders are applied to the images inside the div with class `this`

Comment: But if I do that, the images won't be aligned horizontally

Comment: @CarloVillamor added a new snippet check that too.Instead of adding div inside tr i have added div inside each td

Comment: Ohhhh. So I have to put div inside the td for it to work. My problem is that I will be working with a lot of images like that so I was hoping if I could put the div outside the td, or better, outside the tr occupying multiple tr's then calling the images because I want to remove all those (width="400 px" height="400px"). Is that possible?

Comment: @CarloVillamor You cannot put div as the direct child of table.The valid structure is `<table><tr><td> Content </td></tr></table>`.If you have lot of images add class to the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
.this img {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

to style all images within that specific class.

Answer (score -2):

if you are trying to add css to all of the images you can in your css call it like this :

.this {

*css styles here *

}